# Is there a way to sort descending with a method reference?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

In Java 8, I can sort using a lambda or a method reference:

```
List<String> str = Arrays.asList("a","b","A","B");
//Lambda sort ascending
str.sort(s1, s2) -> s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);    

//Equivalent sort ascending with method reference 
str.sort(String::compareToIgnoreCase);

//Lambda sort descending 
str.sort(s1, s2) -> s2.compareToIgnoreCase(s1);

//Equivalent sort descending with method reference 
???????? How to do it????
```

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Comparator#reversed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--)

```
str.sort(((Comparator<String>)String::compareToIgnoreCase).reversed());
```

or two steps

```
Comparator<String> comp = String::compareToIgnoreCase;
str.sort(comp.reversed());
```